# С помощью чего лучше тестировать десктоп приложение написано на Java, с применением Java?

Tags: java, тестирование

Подскажите, какой фреймфорк для Java, или какую тулу можно заюзать, что бы можно было нормально и комфортно тестировать десктопное приложение написано на Java?
Варианты такие как Sikuli, не особо хотелос бы юзать.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/sikuli/?

Comment: https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX